# How can we keep a navbar fixed on a specific position?

Tags: css, navbar, nav, scrollspy

I'm creating a half-page background image on my HTML and under the image I have scrollspy with a navbar. I wanted to have that navbar fixed on that certain position (not fixed-top or fixed-bottom)

[half-page bg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vywZE.jpg)

When i set it to position: fixed, the navbar is all over the page

[position: fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwb9V.png)

When i set to sticky this happens

[position: sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxImQ.png)

CSS Code

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
.landingImage {
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0%;
    background-image: url("image/bgimage.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/*ID of the nav element*/
#stick {
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm a newbie to this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Do you mean to say you should make your menu fixed after image and it will never change the position? and what about the view when the page scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work

```
#stick {
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100px; /* for height you can use any value */
}
```